# DialogFragment styling works when made programmatically but not in XML style

Tags: android

I have these settings for my `DialogFragment` which works perfect when they are set programmatically! But when I want them as an XML style and want to use this style for all other `DialogFragments`, then it don't work! I want a solution where I can only use the XML style.

**DialogFragment styling programmatically**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    int x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,250, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,250, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int p = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(x, y);

    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.popup_rounded_frame);

    getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setPadding(p,p,p,p);
}
```

**DialogFragment styling in XML**

```
<style name="ArionDialogFragment" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">


    <item name="android:height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:width">100dp</item>

    <item name="android:maxWidth">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">100dp</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/popup_rounded_frame</item>

    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>

</style>
```

**This is how I initiate my DialogFragments:**

```
        popuptest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            PopUP popUP = new PopUP();
            popUP.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.ArionDialogFragment);
            popUP.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"d");


        }
    });
```

Comment: can u paste the code where you are calling this fragment ( from activity/parent fragment)

Comment: @NayanSrivastava I'm calling it from MainActivity.